# How to remove given object from R environment

Tags: r, rm

In R ,this are `object_a/object_b`, i want to remove them from R environment ,
but `rm(c('object_a','object_b'))` can't work. Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
object_a <- c(1:3)
object_b <- c(1:6)
rm(c('object_a','object_b'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
rm(object_a, object_b)
```

Works also with more than 2 objects.

Answer (score 1):

*rm* has a *list* argument:

```
rm(list = c('object_a','object_b'))
```